# When creating external partitioned table in BigQuery, it says: Specifying a schema is disallowed for STORAGE_FORMAT_AVRO

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm following [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs#setting_hivepartitioningoptions_using_the_web_ui) guide from google cloud documentation to create external partitioned table, which is:

Create table from: Google Cloud Storage
Select file from GCS bucket: gs://my_bucket/data/ymd=20200703/*
File format: Avro
Source Data Partitioning, URI Prefix: gs://my_bucket/data/
Table Type: **External**

But when I click create table it says:

> Specifying a schema is disallowed for STORAGE_FORMAT_AVRO

If I use **native tables** instead of **external**, it just works. I also tried gs://my_bucket/data/*, gs://my_bucket/data/, gs://my_bucket/data/**/*, gs://my_bucket/data/ymd=20200703/*, gs://my_bucket/data/ymd=20200703/file-blabla, ... for *Select file from GCS bucket* but no difference.

Any ideas how I can create external partitioned tables in BigQuery? not native?

Comment: Are you trying to create an empty table? Are you defining the database schema?

Comment: @SamuelRomero no, the data is already there. so it's not an empty table, and the schema is auto detected. It's just that if I enable partitioning it fails to do so.

Comment: Not sure if the data layout you are using is the right one, but you can try something like described at this link https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs#performing_incremental_loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with google big query, reported this and they are working on it now.